# Sort table in number order

Tags: sql

I have a table where I have dishes and the sum of how many people like each dish. Now, the table is sort by the name of the dishes but I would like to sort it by the quantity instead.

Here is the code I have came up with so far:

```
SELECT dishes, COUNT(dishes) AS quantity FROM dishes
GROUP BY dishes;
```

Comment: Add an ORDER BY. You should find a SQL tutorial - this is an extremely basic question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT dishes, COUNT(dishes)
FROM dishes
GROUP BY dishes
ORDER BY COUNT(dishes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT dishes, COUNT(dishes) AS quantity FROM dishes
GROUP BY dishes
ORDER BY quantity;
```

Comment: That's not going to work because `quantity` is not a column in the table.

Comment: Using a column alias in the `ORDER BY` is supported by (almost?) every database.

Comment: Oracle definitely doesn't allow it.